# Style TreeView Header. Set Header Unselectable

Tags: c#, header, treeview, styles

how can i style only the header of a tree view ?
I want to make the header unselectable.

Something like:

```
 <TreeViewHeaderStyle>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"  Value="false">
 </TreeViewHeaderStyle>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I edited my answer should work for what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style the `TreeViewItem` in your Window's or Control's resources.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

EDIT:

If you still need to expand via the triangle, but want a disabled header, the solution is a bit dirtier. Many solutions show a complicated restyling of the `HeaderedItemsControl` you can search for that or simply add a `Label` to each `TreeViewItem` and handle a mouse down event. In the below example I wrapped a `Label` inside a grid so that I could style the label as needed. When the `Grid` is clicked the event is handled preventing expansion. If you are only setting the `Label` content, you can just add the `MouseDown` event to the `Label` and ditch the `Grid`.

```
 <TreeViewItem>
     <TreeViewItem.Header>
         <Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
             <Label Content="TEST" IsEnabled="False" />
         </Grid>
     </TreeViewItem.Header>
     <Button Content="Random SubItem"/>
 </TreeViewItem>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: But this styles all TreeViewItem ? I only want to disable to Focus of the Header.

Comment: Do you want both the header and the triangle to be disabled or just the header text?

Comment: Just the header text :)